# Create property of object with form, Angular 5

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, formgroups

I want to create an object for location with two parameters inside it.
I can create with FormGroup an array or strings, but I don't know how to create an Object with two parameters inside. This is the code I am using for:

```
bucketForm: FormGroup; // at the top of the class component

ngOnInit() {
    this.initForm();
  }

private initForm() {
    let bucketName = '';
    let bucketLocation = {};
    let bucketObjects = new FormArray([]);

    this.bucketForm = new FormGroup({
      'name': new FormControl(bucketName, Validators.required),
      'location': // Here I want to create Location Object with two parameters {id: 'Some random number', name: 'New York'},
      'bucketObjects': bucketObjects
    });
    console.log(this.bucketForm);
  }
```

I get the value form .html file of the component, I have a simple form here and it is the full code I am using:

```
<form [formGroup]="bucketForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="name">Bucket Name*</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          id="name"
          formControlName="name">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="bucketLocation">Bucket Location*</label>
        <select
          class="custom-select d-block w-100"
          id="bucketLocation"
          formControlName="location">
          <option
            *ngFor="let locationEl of locations" [value]="locationEl.name">{{ locationEl.name }}
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <button
      type="submit"
      class="btn btn-primary"
      [disabled]="!bucketForm.valid">Create Bucket
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
  </form>
```

This is my bucket model, I am using array of buckets:

```
Bucket {
    id: "BucketExample", // string
    name: "BucketExample", // string
    location: Location, // object { id: string, name: string }
    bucketObjects: Array(0)
}
```

Screenshot: https://d2ffutrenqvap3.cloudfront.net/items/071z2l0Y3N3a2P25463O/print-scr-bucket.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

HTML file:

```
<select class="custom-select d-block w-100"
                id="bucketLocation"
                formControlName="location"
                ngModel>
          <option value="" disabled>Choose...</option>
          <option
            *ngFor="let locationEl of locations" [ngValue]="locationEl">{{ locationEl.name }}
          </option>
        </select>
```

TypeScript file:

```
private initForm() {
    let bucketName = '';
    let bucketLocation = {};
    let bucketObjects = new FormArray([]);

    this.bucketForm = new FormGroup({
      'name': new FormControl(bucketName, Validators.required),
      'location': new FormControl(bucketLocation, Validators.required),
      'bucketObjects': bucketObjects
    });

}
```

I find the solution here, from examples:
[Angular API doc](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor)

Also thanks to @cyberpirate92

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set an object as a value for one of the properties of a form.

To have object as a property, you have to use a `FormGroup` instead of a `FormControl`.

You can have a `FormGroup` within another `FormGroup`, so your `bucketForm` should be,

```
this.bucketForm = new FormGroup({
  'name': new FormControl(bucketName, Validators.required),
  'location': new FormGroup({
      id: new FormControl(Math.random()),
      name: new FormControl('')
  }),
  'bucketObjects': bucketObjects
});
```

And to set the value of a `select` control as an object instead of primitive values, you must use [`ngValue`](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgSelectOption#ngValue)

Since we are going to set an object directly, 
provide the form control object as input, instead of providing the `formControlName` attribute.

**i,e** instead of

```
formControlName="location"
```

use

```
[formControl]="bucketForm.get('location')"
```

So your HTML should look something like this,

```
<select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="bucketLocation" [formControl]="bucketForm.get('location')">
   <option
     *ngFor="let locationEl of locations" [ngValue]="locationEl">{{ locationEl.name }}
   </option>
</select>
```

### [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-control-select-complex-object-cv4kaj)

Comment: Here is the screenshot: https://d2ffutrenqvap3.cloudfront.net/items/071z2l0Y3N3a2P25463O/print-scr-bucket.jpg

I think you understand me now. I want to add Bucket to an array of Buckets with form. Bucket must get location id and name from the form.

Comment: @Martin Check [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-control-select-complex-object-cv4kaj) stackblitz

Comment: show me this error:
https://d2ffutrenqvap3.cloudfront.net/items/232u2N1Z1a00251s0P3n/Image%202018-03-20%20at%2010.17.42%20PM.png .
Problem with [formControl]="bucketForm.get('location')"

Comment: Never mind, It's happening even in the stackblitz I shared

Comment: Yes, it works fine. How can I resolve the error? And another problem in select box for bucket location is empty on the first load.
https://d2ffutrenqvap3.cloudfront.net/items/0Q1a1t0O1M2Q0l0e2f0L/Image%202018-03-20%20at%2010.34.30%20PM.png
Not selected first bucket location automatically

Comment: I resolved the problem, thank you very much! I posted the solution. :)